# Changing Android repositories without using more bandwidth

Tags: android, git, repository, open-source

I'm stuck in a big problem here.

I synced Android's Master branch but I what I really needed was android-6.0.1_r63 branch.

As I don't have enough bandwidth, how can I sync android-6.0.1_r63 branch without using more bandwidth like it did in android-master branch?

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: When you say you synced Android's master branch, do you mean `git clone`? If so, did you pass the `--single-branch` option?

Comment: I did "repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest" . So I forgot to specify the branch therefore it was defaulted to master branch.

Comment: What do you mean by not enough bandwidth, it would take too long? Or you don't have enough data allotment left on your internet connection?

Comment: Actually both. I just don't want to waste this much data on AOSP again. Can't I sync android-6.0.1_r63 referencing the AOSP-Master branch by " repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-6"

Comment: edit : Actually both. I just don't want to waste this much data on AOSP again. Can't I sync android-6.0.1_r63 referencing the AOSP-Master branch by " repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-6.0.1_r63 --reference=~/android-master " ?